# Does refreshing a page create a new database connection?

Tags: php

Say you have an index.php, which creates a class/instance called new app().
In the app class it creates another instance called Database, which makes a connection to the mysql. If I constantly refresh, will it continue to create new app instance, which then opens more mysql connection or will it terminate pervious connection and just opens 1.

Comment: you will just have 1

Comment: @nogad would that be the same as you move around the website?

Comment: i believe @nogad is actually incorrect. when you execute a script you create a new connection and when the script finishes that connection is terminated unless you use [persistent connections](http://php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php) ([PDO example](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php#example-1029))

Comment: @nogad is indeed correct unless you have a very long query (in terms of execution time).  Database query didn't stop its execution unless it encountered an error (even if you close the browser while it is executing). In short, if you refresh the browser faster than query's execution, it will create a new connection. If you are not concern about query execution, nogad's comment is enough.

Comment: @nogad is wrong. There will be a new instance for every page load. someone is right, when the script ends, the instance is gone - so if the script is still running and you keep opening up new pages that launch the same script before the last ones complete, then there will be multiple instances.

Comment: im probably right and wrong depending on how your interpreting this. I'm thinking along the lines that once the script finished the connection is closed, a refresh creates a new connection - so there is always only one connection. Constant refreshes wont create extra connections, also they are shared if created with the same credentials. those calling me wrong are just interpreting this differently

Comment: That's only true per connection, so if you have multiple people running the script they are all separate (simultaneous) connections. It's more accurate to say there is a new connection which each run that is closed at the end.